# How can I use the same $(document).ready(function() for multiple inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm new to JavaScript/jQuery, I have 4 date selections within a form using DatePicker.

Seeing as the settings are the same, I tried using dp1 for all 4 date selections but it doesn't work. The first date selections work but the 3 others don't.

So at the moment I am doing it like this, but it seems pointless extra code as the settings are the same.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dp1').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
  });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dp2').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
  });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dp3').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
  });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dp4').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
  });
</script>
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: you only need on document.ready function, everything in there will function just like javascritpt.

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can :) And notice that you don't even need to use 4 different datepicker functions since you can use jQuery selectors to target all 4 datepickers like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#dp1, #dp2, #dp3, #dp4').datepicker({

     autoclose: true,
     format: "yyyy-mm-dd"

     });

  });
 </script>
```

Comment: It is better to add a class to all of these like: `class="dp"`

Comment: Depends. I did not know the whole situation of the op, how many there are going to be, what else use ID has, does class have any other uses etc so as far as I know according to the code given I wrote the ID's. Usually tough the class would be better of course

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  You can do this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dp1').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
     $('#dp2').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
     $('#dp3').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
     $('#dp4').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How did you write your name like that?

Comment: Alternately, you could give all of those inputs the same class name ("datepicker") and then just do this once: $('.datepicker').datepicker({ ... });

Comment: I agree that the solution proposed by [Defain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25146664/361762) is more elegant, but I answered this in this way because the OP is addmittedly new at jQuery and I wanted to illustrate that code written in $(document).ready() does not need to be limited to one statement.

Comment: @daveͤͮͣͩ seriously how did you write your name like that?

Comment: My name uses [Combining Diacritical Marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) from the Unicode character set.  You don't get all the letters, but it was enough for me.  In HTML it would be written: dave &#868;&#878;&#867;&#873;

Answer (score 0):

or (just give them all one css class `all_dps`)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.all_dps').datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });

});
</script>
```